# Create Powershell Hashtable and Export to Excel

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get some information from a hash table, when it displays on the screen, it all outputs correctly. When I try to export it to excel I get some strange output.

The code I use is

```
$hash = @{}

$disk = Get-AzureRmDisk
foreach ($d in $disk) {
    $hash.Add(($d).Id.Split("/")[-1],($d).Id.Split("/")[-5])
}

$hash | Export-Csv C:\managed\disks.csv
```

Still learning hashtables so excuse the simple approach :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Export-Csv` expects *multiple* objects, not one big dictionary. To extract each entry from the hashtable and feed them to `Export-Csv` one by one, you can call `GetEnumerator()` on the hashtable:

```
$hash.GetEnumerator() |Select Name,Value |Export-Csv C:\managed\disks.csv
```

---

If you don't actually need the hashtable later on in your script, you can skip that step completely and just grab the values you need with `Select-Object`:

```
Get-AzureRmDisk |Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_.Id.Split("/")[-1]}},@{Name='Value';Expression={$_.Id.Split("/")[-5]}} |Export-Csv C:\managed\disks.csv
```

Comment: R Jessen, thanks that makes sense now, would it be possible to get vm name too, using something like `($disk).managedby` property, would I need to put that into an array?

Comment: Add it to the list of properties after `Select-Object`: `Select-Object ManagedBy,@{Name='Name';Expression={$_.Id.Split("/")[-1]}},@{Name='Value';Expression={$_.Id.Split("/")[-5]}}`